# How to use dynamic imports with typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

Im doing typescript and I want to do dynamic imports based on commands. I have this setup which has no issues

```
static async GetCommand(command:string):Promise<(this: Discord.Message, ...args: string[]) => Promise<void>> {
    const f = (await import(`./classes/roles/everyone/commands/give_money/command`));
    return f.default;
}
```

but that is hardcoded to a fixed import location. I want to make it dynamic like this

```
static async GetCommand(command:string):Promise<(this: Discord.Message, ...args: string[]) => Promise<void>> {
    const f = (await import(`./classes/roles/everyone/commands/${command}/command`));
    return f.default;
}
```

but then it complains that `f` is of type `any` and doesn't compile as a result. How can I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> then it complains that f is of type any and doesn't compile as a result.

If you have a dynamic string as an argument to `import` TypeScript assumed any.

> How can I fix this?

Add an explicit annotation if you want the error to go away:

```
static async GetCommand(command:string):Promise<(this: Discord.Message, ...args: string[]) => Promise<void>> {
    const f: any = (await import(`./classes/roles/everyone/commands/${command}/command`));
    return f.default;
}
```

Comment: I get `Unsafe assignment of an any value.`. I want that to go away too.